# HTML/CSS issue: div positioned on the right

Tags: html, css, repeat, direction

I have searched a lot to solve this issue but came up empty-handed.

Basically, I have a div that is repeated on the x-axis from the center of the screen to the left side:

```
#example{
left:50%;
width:50%;
background-color:red;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

This gives the div the illusion of only repeating to the left side of the screen, which is what I want it to do. It does it. My problem is that I want to have another div that does the exact same thing except to the right. This code straight-up doesn't work:

```
#exampleright{
right:50%;
width:50%;
background-color:red;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

What's the problem? Is there a solution? Or is there another way to do this? Thanks!!

Comment: Or a jsfiddle displaying what you've tried would be nice pl0x.

Comment: Here is jsFiddle with HTML and modified CSS.. http://jsfiddle.net/Lk6J2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using `float` instead of `left` and `right`:

```html
<div class="example example-left">example left</div>
<div class="example example-right">example right</div>
```

```css
div.example {
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

div.example.example-left {
    float:left;
}

div.example.example-right{
    float:right
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AAKRP/2/

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't think of that!! Thanks so much man!